# MySQL 8 Replication

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, replication, mysql-8.0

I've got this error message:
Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 25883. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for source to send event
                  Master_Host: 173.249.4.25
                  Master_User: master1
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000010
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 85083434
               Relay_Log_File: db-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 318
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1032
                   Last_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 25883. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 503
              Relay_Log_Space: 943477677
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1032
               Last_SQL_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 25883. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
                  Master_UUID: 5ccfd742-1a98-11e9-86f7-ac1f6b1dd75c
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: 
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 220327 13:18:25
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
           Master_TLS_Version: 
       Master_public_key_path: 
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace: 
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Of note:  **Last_SQL_Error:** Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 25883. See error log and/or `performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table` for more details about this failure or others, if any.

Answer (score 0):

1.use pt-table-checksum tool for master and slave data

2.skip the error

mysql> stop slave;

mysql> set @@session.gtid_next='xxxxx';

mysql> begin;
mysql> commit;

mysql> set @@session.gtid_next=automatic;

mysql> start slave;

mysql> show slave status \G

Comment: Same error message.